# Sorting UITableView according to alphabetical or numerical order on button click

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uitableview

I have customized uitableview cell with four labels  and also four arrays which hold data for each labels. label1 contain name of object and label 2 contain price label 3 and label 4 contain other data. Now there is two buttons , on first button click i want to sort the table in alphabetical order of object name and on second button click i want to sort according to price ..Please guide me how to do it.. Here is my code..

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

details=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"dress",@"dress",@"dress",@"dress",@"dress",@"",
          @"dress",@"",@"dress",nil];
newPrice=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"500",@"1000",@"5000",@"2100",@"1222",@"100",@"5223",@"465",@"3216",nil];
oldPrice=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"200",@"900",@"6000",@"2220",@"1000",@"",@"5000",@"",@"",nil];


dataList=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Praline rose dress",@"Praline rose dress",@"Multi Colored dress",@"Multi Colored dress",@"Multi Colored dress",@"Praline rose dress",
          @"Multi Colored dress",@"Multi Colored dress",@"Praline rose dress",nil];

searchData=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[searchData addObjectsFromArray:dataList];

dataTable.delegate=self;
dataTable.dataSource=self;
[dataTable reloadData];

  -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"CellIdentifier";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) { cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]
                            initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                            reuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    UILabel *labelOne = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70, 10, 140, 20)];
    labelOne.tag = 100;
    labelOne.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    labelOne.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:labelOne];
    [labelOne release];


    labelTwo = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(260, 10, 140, 20)];
    labelTwo.tag = 101;
    labelTwo.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    labelTwo.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
    labelTwo.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.25098 green:0.447059 blue:0.07451 alpha:1];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:labelTwo];
    [labelTwo release];


    UILabel *label3 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70, 30, 140, 20)];
    label3.tag = 102;
    label3.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    label3.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:label3];
    [label3 release];


    UILabel *label4 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(260, 30, 140, 20)];
    label4.tag = 103;
    label4.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    label4.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:label4];
    [label4 release];
}

  UILabel *labelOne = (UILabel *) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:100];
labelOne.text = [searchData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

labelTwo = (UILabel *) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:101];
labelTwo.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",[newPrice objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

UILabel *label3 = (UILabel *) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:102];
label3.text=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",[details objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

UILabel *label4 = (UILabel *) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:103];
label4.text=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",[oldPrice objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];



return cell;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```
if(btn.tag == 500)
{
    aSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"OrderDate" ascending:YES];
}
if(btn.tag == 501)
{
    aSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"CustomerGuid" ascending:YES];     
}
if (searching) {
    [temp_details sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:aSortDescriptor]];
} 
else{
    [orders sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:aSortDescriptor]];
}
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

set the tags for two buttons and you can follow the above method to sort 
those keys are the from dictionary which set to the label in the table view i am sorting those labels using the button pressed

Comment: @ Krishna,.. What is meant by initwithkey: , I have read the documentation but didnt understand..would you please elaborate.thanks

Comment: those keys from dictionary which i am setting to the tableview label so sorting the dictionary and i am reloading the table

Comment: So i have to use dictionary in my App? I havnt use any dictionary yet.

Comment: you can use mutablarray or what ever using to set for lable

Answer (score 0):

You can see NSArray class reference about following methods.

Sorting

```
sortedArrayHint
sortedArrayUsingFunction:context:
sortedArrayUsingFunction:context:hint:
sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:
sortedArrayUsingSelector:
sortedArrayUsingComparator:
sortedArrayWithOptions:usingComparator:
```

As for your problem, you can sort strings by

```
[strings sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)]
```